# How to allow users to pick dates using Python

Tags: date, datetime, python-2.7, datepicker

I'm new to Python and have searched everywhere for days for this solution, so I apologize in advance if the answer is posted somewhere that I've not been able to find.  Nothing I find addresses this exactly the way I need.

I'm trying to write code to allow the user to pick a start date and end date. I have a csv file with a field for dates in this format: `1/1/2013 0:00` and I want to allow the user to pick dates from any range within 1/1/2013 to 6/30/2013.

I've imported the following, then my problem starts immediately as I'm getting `AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'strptime'`, but I'm reading that it is an attribute. I'm also trying to avoid the use of any GUI; just need a straightforward way to allow user input parameters. My endgoal here is to convert it to a tool in ArcGIS for user input parameters, which I can do, but I need to create the script correctly first.

```
import arcpy, os, sys                      
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

startDate = datetime.date.strptime(userdateString, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Thank you so much in advance for any direction you can give! I am quite confused by all of this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This eliminates the attribute error:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> userdateString = '2013-2-1'
>>> datetime.strptime(userdateString, '%Y-%m-%d')
datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 1, 0, 0)
```

Note that the code to use depends on precisely what one imports.  If I use `import date` in place of `from datetime import datetime`, note that, as a result of python's naming conventions, the method to use is`datetime.datetime.strptime` rather than `datetime.strptime` as above:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> userdateString = '2013-2-1'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(userdateString, '%Y-%m-%d')
datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 1, 0, 0)
```

ADDENDUM:  Yes, you can change date formats:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s = '2-1-2013'
>>> datetime.strptime(s, '%m-%d-%Y')
datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 1, 0, 0)
>>> s = '2/1/2013'
>>> datetime.strptime(s, '%m/%d/%Y')
datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Hi @John1024, Thank you for your input. I've tried using your example, but I'm getting:  AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'. I have imported datetime, but I don't know why this isn't working.

Comment: Hi again John, your code ran, but I had to take out the third line datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 1, 0, 0) or I would get 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'. I don't know why that is, because I did import datetime at the beginning. I'm afraid that taking it out will have ill effects later on, but I can't run it otherwise.  Thanks so much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @user3081899, that line `datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 1, 0, 0)` was not code: that was the result of running the previous line.  When running the python interpreter interactively, ">>>" is the prompt.  Thus the lines preceded by ">>>" were entered into the intepreter.  The last line, the one without the prompt, was python's response.  When developing, I recommend trying things out interactively because it makes it so much easier to debug.

Comment: Ahhh...okay. I'm running the script in PythonWin, which is why I don't see ">>>" as the prompt, but rather that is in the interactive window.  In other words, I'm seeing it opposite from the way you are: the line or lines that's Python's response show up in the interactive window where it's preceded by ">>>".  Also, I imported datetime and date. I guess I only needed one or the other?Thanks again!

Comment: OK.  That prompt issue would be confusing.  I think that you will find that much of the python world relies on the ">>>" as prompt convention and it is explicitly part of the doctest module which is in the standard library.  And, yes, to run strptime, you only need the datetime import.  (I don't know if your code is using `date` elsewhere.)  After I develop a script, I often run `pylint` on it.  `pylint` is an imperfect program but it will, among other things, report unused imports.

Comment: @user3081899, Also, I update the answer with different date formats.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> userdateString= '2013-2-1'
>>> startDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(userdateString, '%Y-%m-%d')
>>> print startDate
2013-02-01 00:00:00
```

You need to include an extra datetime between datetime and strptime.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your help! The script runs when I use just one datetime instead of two, although I see it worked for you. When I use both, I get an attribute error 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'. When I use just one, I get the same result as you. I am using 2.7.2 so I'm wondering if this has something to do with it. Thanks so much, though! Really appreciate it!

Comment: That's pretty interesting. I'm using 2.7.3 so maybe there was a change between the versions. When I try using one datetime it crashes with the following message: 

'"Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    startDate = datetime.strptime(userdateString, "%Y-%m=%d")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime''

Comment: Hi again, Please see John's explanation below about why this is.  I think this is the problem. I forgot to ask, does the format have to be '2013-2-1'? I'm reading everywhere that it does, but the csv file that I use as my input file has this format 1/1/2013. Therefore, when I convert the script to the script tool in ArcGIS, it doesn't recognize the format.  Thanks again!